# Biding function to events after appending html AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

Here is my question being asked, after searching for answer through similar questions, but not understanding my failure:

I trigger html new form, by changing data to one of it's select input field. the form is being replaced successfully via AJAX response + JQUERY binding (after I change input value to its first input field, AJAX call is being carried out to the server written in PHP. the response of the AJAX is a new but almost identical html form created by the php server) I see the answer form in network tab of chrome, and its perfect. I bind it to form's parent div element perfectly. the forms swap perfectly. However  the same process of triggering change for the second time fails - nothing happens when I change data for the same select input field of the new form. here is my code in JQUERY: 
.membership_form is the class of that select input field that triggers the change.

```
$(".membership_form").life("change",function (e) {

            var membership = $(this).val();
            var form = $(this).closest('form');
            var user_id = form.data('user');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: sogo.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    'action': 
                     'sogo_print_fields_according_to_membership',
                    'membership': membership,
                    'user_id': user_id,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if(user_id==99){
                        // meaning add user screen
                        $('#inside_form_fields_user_99').html(response);
                    } else{
                        // regular user_management screen          
 $('#inside_form_fields_user_'+user_id).html(response);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: try `$(document).on('change', '.membership_form', function(){})`

Comment: not `life` but `live`

Comment: wait maybe i was so tired to do such a mistake ... $(document) i didnt try to use... maybe you are right.. it should be binded to entire document !

Comment: Try onChange="memberFunction();" in your select element, and call your function as function memberFunction(){....} and write the code inside the function.

Comment: Se0ng11 you are correct i want to grant you with correct answer

Answer (score 0):

try $(document).on('change', '.membership_form', function(){})